# JavaScript file partially only works on index.html but not on subpages

Tags: javascript, html, supabase

I am trying to fetch data from a Supabase table to update the content (innerHTML) of a HTML h1 (acting as username).
I correctly imported Supabase (connection tested and works).

However, I only get the logs from JavaScript in the browser console of the index.html file, but not on the subpages. My file structure looks as follows:

root

- index.html
- script.js
- views
  -- subpage.html
- 00_setup
  --supabase.js

In the subpage, the script is correctly implemented: `<script src="../script.js" type="module"></script>`. The Supabase scripts are correctly implemented as well and show their testing console logs, on the subpages as well.

This is the script:

```
//import supabase
import { supa } from './00_setup/supabase.js';

console.log('Script.js loaded')

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log('DOM Loaded');      //Prevent loading script before DOM is loaded
})

var userId = 1; //userID of logged-in user for further use

var profileUsername;

async function getUsername(userId) {
    const { data, error } = await supa
        .from('users')
        .select('username')
        .eq('id', userId)   //Get username where db id = userId 

    if (error) {
        console.error('Could not retrieve username from database')  //Add error handling
    }
    else {
        profileUsername = data[0].username; //Assign username to profileUsername
        $('#profile_username').innerHTML = profileUsername; //Replace default username with actual username
    }
    console.log('console.log in function ' + profileUsername);
}
//Test
(async () => {
    await getUsername(userId);
    console.log('Async test: ' + profileUsername);
})();

//Trigger getUsername on pageload
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    getUsername();
})
```

Curiously, the logs for DOM and script loading are showing up everywhere.
The console.logs for 'async test' & 'console.log in function' show up on the index page but nowhere else.
I also get a console error on the subpage:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Does anybody know where the error is here?
I mainly use Firefox, but also encountered the same error on Chrome.

The console logs where applied for testing, but only show up on index. I tried re-linking a new file (checked with `console.log`) and paste the code in there, but with the same result.

Comment: If you have an Uncaught SyntaxError, then you can hardly expect any console.log statements to still run ...

Comment: Well the error appears to be that you've got an `import` statement in a non-module script. That error will stop the script from doing anything. You can import the script with `<script type=module>` to make it a module.

Comment: Also, that comment in the "DOMContentLoaded" handler does not make sense; that event handler won't prevent anything.

Comment: @Pointy as stated in the inline-code, I import the script as a module… it won't work either

Comment: @CBroe do you know what could be the error here? The exact same file works on the index.html and the statements run there…

Comment: It's not that you import it **as** a module; you have to use `import` **in** a module.

Comment: @Pointy would that explain why it does work on index but not on the subpages? If so, could you explain how I can fix it?
I am relatively new to working with supabase and never encountered that error before…

Comment: Any time you want to `import` from a `<script>` on a web page, that script (where you use `import`) has to be marked `type=module` in the `<script>` tag. It doesn't matter what you're importing (well, what module; obviously the imported thing should "know" it's a module).